# I have css file in frontend folder but i need to apply that in my backend index.php page, how do i do this in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have `style.css` file in `frontend/web/css/style.css`, with same class name in `backend/view/site/index.php` i need to give path that `css` to my backend `index.php`.
How should i do that.

on my `backend/view/site/index.php` page i have place below code

```
use frontend\assets\AppAssets;
.
.
.
.
.
.
<?php $this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/css/style.css', ['depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]); ?>
```

Comment: Use [Assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Comment: Use `AssetManager` but remember with `$sourcePath` option as per your requirements otherwise wont work